# How do I trigger the product's variation event

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

[image]

My product has a variation called "Session". For reasons, I want to change it using an unrelated button.

[image]

How do I trigger its event using js when a button is pressed.

Comment: Here you can find a list of JS events available in WooCommerce for product variations in the frontend: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/385043/200545

Comment: I already figured it out and I posted a solution but someone decided to delete my answer.